# Reading/Creating Configuration File in Spark/Scala according to Environment

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've created one Spark /scala Code in which currently I'm giving Hardcoded value as per my dev configuration while creating spark session.
but I want to pass this value from configuration file so at run time it can take values from file based on Envi(dev,sit,prod).I have created on app.Property file
under resource folder(in eclipse )
and wrote below code.

```
    app.property
    dev {
    My_App {
    spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url = "jdbc://(devurl)"
    }
    }
    sit {
    My_App {
    spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url = "jdbc://(siturl)"
    }
    }
    prod {
    My_App {
    spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url = "jdbc://(produrl)"
    }
    }
    //scala code(sample_code)
    object 1st_layer {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparksession = SparkSession.builder().appName("My_App").config("spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url","url").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
    var a1=sparksession.sql(" load stmt")
    sparksession.stop()
    }
    }
```

Please suggest how should i do this so it can read the configuration based on environments.?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done by send spark environment variables and based on that load the proper config from the configuration files. Assuming that `env` is your environment variable where you pass the value at runtime you can do something like below

```
val stmtQuery = ConfigFactory.load("app.property").get("${env.toLowerCase}.My_App.spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url")
```

based on that value you can query further.

You can read from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) how you can pass evironment JVM parameters to spark

Comment: Hi @dumitru..I tried this but got below Error..Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BadPath: path parameter: Invalid path '${env.toLowerCase}.My_App.spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url': Token not allowed in path expression: '${'env.toLowerCase'}' (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)

Comment: spark-submit \
--class classname\
prject jar
filepath
dev
and in code used like this:
val env:String = args(1)
val config = ConfigFactory.load(args(0)).getConfig("${env.toLowerCase}.My_App.spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url")